# Converting String to a List

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I am trying to read entries in a file and convert them into a List

```
with open('myfile1.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

print(lines)            ###['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2']
print(type(lines))      ###<type 'list'>

catch = (json.dumps(lines))         ###For replacing single quotes to double
print(catch)                        ###["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"]
print(type(catch))                  ###<type 'str'>

catch_1 = list(catch.split("''"))    ###Converting str to list
print(catch_1)                       ###['["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"]']
```

Is there is a better way to replace quotes from single to double without changing the type.

```
File entries :
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2

Expected Output :
["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"]
 <type 'list'>
```

Please let me know, thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to replace the single quotes from `['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2']` to `["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"]`?

Comment: @RoadRunner yes.

Comment: But they are the same thing?

Comment: Yes, but I have a requirement in my code where it takes the input only as double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Strings surrounded by `'` or `"` are exactly the same. It's no difference between `["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"]` or `['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2']` internally. It's only a difference when you print it. If you want to have double quotes when you're printing the list, you could do this:

```
a = ['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2']
print(str(a).replace("'", '"'))
```

This will print `["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"]`.

To answer your question *"Is there is a better way to replace quotes from single to double without changing the type?"*. The quotation marks does not exist inside your program! The list and the strings have no concept of quotation mark. They are only added when printing the list or when you're converting the list to a string.